# SJ.iwc is undefined in IE inside iframe - Unable to get property SignalR of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, signalr, signalr-hub

[image]

Unable to start SignalR in IE while using inside **iframe**. It is not working on any of IE version. It is works fine when we render normally in browser. Problem only with **iframe**.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery")

        <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/signalr")

        <script>
            $(function () {
            var hub = $.connection.signalrHub;
            hub.client.connection = function () {
            };
            SJ.iwc.SignalR.start();
        });
        </script>
```

My Bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/jquery") { Orderer = order }.Include(
            "~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"
           ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/signalr") { Orderer = order }.Include(
            "~/scripts/Signalr/iwc-all.min.js",
            "~/scripts/Signalr/signalr-patch.js",
            "~/scripts/Signalr/iwc-signalr.js"
           ));
```

Any one faced this issue in IE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed by giving my script section inside `@section scripts`

```
@section scripts
{
     <script>
            $(function () {
            var hub = $.connection.signalrHub;
            hub.client.connection = function () {
            };
            SJ.iwc.SignalR.start();
        });
        </script>
}
```

Found this in below link:
[SignalR $.connection is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199070/signalr-connection-is-undefined)